# PrimeNG - Message

Tags: angular, primeng

In PrimeNG (Angular components), [*Message*](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages) is available in these three packages.

Are these all the same?

Seems all these work to display the messages.

```
import { Message } from 'primeng/components/common/message';
import { Message } from 'primeng/components/common/api';
import { Message } from 'primeng/api';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each of them refers to the same *Message* interface.

The best to be sure is to read the source code.

In [primeng/components/common/api](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/api.ts#L11) for instance, you can see that the line

```
export { Message } from './message';
```

refers to the file 
[primeng/components/common/message](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/common/message.ts) where the interface is described :

```
export interface Message {
    severity?: string;
    summary?: string;
    detail?: string;
    id?: any;
    key?: string;
    life?: number;
    sticky?: boolean;
    closable?: boolean;
    data?: any;
}
```